# I am only seeing 1:50 of estimated run time on a new MacBook Pro battery. Problems?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, power

I have bought brand new MacBook pro 15-inch model with highest specifications in this June. I have also installed newest Mac OS, Lion.

However, how it could be strange, when cable is not plugged it, battery shows me that there is only max 1:50 of vitality (nevertheless, despite the fact that there is written in the official web page (http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html) that the battery work is "up to 7 hrs wireless web".

I do not know what the problem is, is this OS problem or the issue with the battery.

---

**Update:**

Okay, after all your recommendations it shows me almost 4 hours on 98% of battery. Here is the screenshot (is it normal to have 4 hours with these processes running?):

[image: Processes]

Comment: For a new mac, you can always call apple and make sure you run a good calibration since that number on the menu bar can be off before the mac has calibrated the individual battery you have. It will also set up precedent if you want to exchange it should the calibration not resolve the issue. You have more exchange options typically in the first two weeks, but do call them sooner if you have any doubts.

Comment: Also, the 1:50 is a combination of how much energy is stored as well as how fast the system is draining. You could just have a process stuck on the CPU and the hard drive constantly indexing content. If you don't get more than 4 or 5 hours on an 99% idle, fully charged MacBook Pro you are right to suspect OS or hardware issues.

Comment: Is it normal to have 4 hours with these processes running (look at the picture above)?

Comment: That seems perfectly normal for you have (at that moment) low CPU but WiFi+Bluetooth on, several network always running programs like skype/twitter. If you turn off the radios, wait 4 minutes, expect 35 to 65 more minutes on the estimate, quit all apps, it might even show 5.5 or 6 when fully charged. Looks fine to me as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should try to reset the SMC and then calibrate the battery.

Calibrate the battery by charging it all the way and let it stay charged for 2 hours (you can use it as long as it's plugged in), then using it until you get a pop-up that says that your computer is running on reserve power. Disregard that and make sure that anything that you're working on is saved. Use the computer until it shuts itself off. Let it sleep that way for 5 hours, and then after those 5 hours plug it in and let it charge up all the way.

To reset the SMC:
1)Shut down the computer.

2)Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected.

3)On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.

4)Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.

5)Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Comment: Great advice - perhaps also check the activity monitor for CPU and disk io after the calibration?

Answer (score 4):

What are you doing when you are testing?  The "up to 7 hours" is for basic web surfing with little computation going on. If you're pushing the system hard, it's inevitable that estimated battery life will show as lower.

Estimated battery life is essentially (battery level remaining / current power usage). As usage goes up, estimated life goes down.  That's standard for all laptops, by the way.  Of course, all manufacturers quote the highest life value, but then most laptops don't spend much of their time being pushed hard.