# Why my MacBook Pro 15" (2011) power adapter turns orange?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, battery

I bought an early-2011 MacBook Pro 15" (highest-spec model) in June. It's running Lion.

I have a problem which happens occasionally. My power adapter (while plugged in) from time to time (particularly when I play games) turns orange and shows me on the bottom of the screen that there is "0:09" or "0:10" minutes left. However, when I push on the battery menu icon for the detailed information, it shows me "99% Full".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read it somewhere before ([here](http://appleguru.org/blog/2011/04/12/2011-macbook-pro-battery-not-charging-under-gpu-load/)) that on some heavy loads (especially GPU loads), 2011 MacBook Pro charger may not supply enough charge. There are no official confirmations, though, as far as I know.

Please check, however, that the "0:09" minutes are referred to the remaining time and not the "remaining time until fully charged". I suppose it is the latter.

I may also point out (but only as a last thought) that if you keep your Mac always under charge, the battery may stop charging at certain times to preserve lifetime.

Comment: The battery actually stops charging as soon as it's full. It will then slowly (over several days) loose a little capacity, and when this reaches a certain threshold (97% full or so) it will be recharged to full again.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that your battery is defective.

If you go to `System Information > Power`, what do you see under `"Battery Information" - "Charge Information"`?

Mine says:

```
Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh): 4693
  Fully Charged: Yes
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 4744
Health Information:
  Cycle Count: 219
  Condition: Normal
```

Comment: It shows me:

"  
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh): 6946
  Fully Charged: Yes
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 6946
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count: 6
  Condition: Normal
  Battery Installed: Yes
  Amperage (mA): 290
  Voltage (mV): 12532
"

Comment: It seems normal... If you use you Mac on battery, how long the battery lasts? Did you try resetting your battery by discharging it completely, leaving it discharged for a few hours, then completely charging it?

Comment: It lasts me 2-4 hours (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22162/i-am-only-seeing-150-of-estimated-run-time-on-a-new-macbook-pro-battery-problem). Yes.

Answer (score 0):

First, unlug your Mac and use it until the battery is at  2% or 3%. Then, shutdown your Mac and plug in again. After that battery should be fully charged.

Comment: This old method of refreshing the battery is not recommended for MacBooks with non-replaceable batteries.